Speed test on PC is different from the speed test on the router (2000 Mbps~ versus 1500 Mbps~)
My Configration:

Connection: FTTH 2.5 Gbps
Router: Asus AX88U Pro (with 2.5 Gbps WAN and 2.5 Gbps LAN)
2.5 Gbps network card on motherboard (MAG Z790 TOMAHAWK MAX WIFI 7) with updated driver

I have tried two Cat7 cables and one Cat6, using the same speed test service (Ookla) against the same server, but on the router, I get over 2000 Mbps, while on the PC, I don't exceed 1500 Mbps. I have set the network card "speed and duplex" to automatic and then forced it to 2.5 Gbps, but the result hasn't changed.
Below are some screenshots.
Speed test on PC (tried multiple times)

Speed test on router

The ethernet driver

What else can I check?
Thanks

Have you proven that your NIC can do 2.5Gbps? If not, connect it to another PC's 2.5G NIC (possibly via 2.5G ports on a switch) and run some iperf tests. Also, have you tried connecting the PC directly to the ONT, to take the router out of the picture? Maybe your router's NAT implementation doesn't reach full 2.5Gbps wire speed.

How is the PC connected to the router? Directly through the LAN cable?

Yes, from ONT with cat7 directly on the Router's Wan port (2.5 Gbps) and from the LAN port (2.5Gbps) with a cat7 directly on the PC on the Lan (2.5Gbps). Spiff's suggestions seem like good starting points to do other tests.

Sorry but among the thousand things to do (and not having top priority on this issue) I did not follow your advice. But today I saw that the MTU of the network card is set to 1300, and by changing it to 1500 I can get just over 1.7Gbps. One little step forward.
